# Monitoring Multiple Instances of camel web application in a single Dashboard

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

I have a camel web application for writing API's,which was deployed in multiple servers.I want a monitoring tool which can integrate these clustered instances and can monitor the Metrices of the application.I have looked into HawtIO but can it monitor all the server instances in a single Dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Fabric8 (or JBoss Fuse in that sense) you can use Fabric to manage and monitor all your instances in one place. Fabric8 also uses Hawtio for this purpose.